# AudioKit error messages with microphone input

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, audiokit

I am working on an amplitude-based visualizer for macOS using the latest versions of AudioKit (4.9.3), Swift (5.1.3), Xcode (11.3), and macOS (10.15.2). I had this working at one time (using earlier versions of each of those things), but now I get the following error messages at runtime:

> 2019-12-14 17:48:45.549957-0500 Dockside2[903:10790] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id  F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
>
> 2019-12-14 17:48:45.564757-0500 Dockside2[903:10790]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
>
> 2019-12-14 17:48:45.566473-0500 Dockside2[903:10790] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:790   couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
>
> 2019-12-14 17:48:45.582337-0500 Dockside2[903:10790] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:1063:SetOutputFormat: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(hwFormat))]

This is the function I call to initialize AudioKit:

```
func startAudioKit() {
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
    input = AKMicrophone()
    amplitudeTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(input)
    AudioKit.output = AKBooster(amplitudeTracker, gain: 0)
    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit did NOT START")
    }
    input.start()
    amplitudeTracker?.start()
}
```

Can anyone make heads or tails of these errors? Extensive searches haven’t yielded anything.

As far as the error regarding AggregateDevices, that's interesting because I am not trying to use an aggregate audio device. I am just trying to get it to work with the default microphone input. *However*, I should mention that in a previous version of my app, which was actually working at one point, I *was* using an aggregate device via SoundFlower for the input. I have since uninstalled SoundFlower entirely and removed the aggregate inputs from Audio MIDI Setup.

Update: If I run the MicrophoneAnalysis example exactly as provided from AudioKit.io, that doesn’t work for me either. I get these similar error messages:

> 2019-12-17 20:00:49.324667-0500 MicrophoneAnalysis[32636:1283453] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id  F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
>
> 2019-12-17 20:00:49.346706-0500 MicrophoneAnalysis[32636:1283453]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
>
> 2019-12-17 20:00:49.347044-0500 MicrophoneAnalysis[32636:1283453]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
>
> 2019-12-17 20:00:49.370055-0500 MicrophoneAnalysis[32636:1283453] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioIONodeImpl.mm:1064:SetOutputFormat: (format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate)]
>
> 2019-12-17 20:00:49.370288-0500 MicrophoneAnalysis[32636:1283453] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate

Comment: The 1st error message goes away if I add an Audio Input = YES entitlement. The other errors remain.

Comment: In addition to the entitlement, there may also be a new "Privacy - microphone usage" thing on the new MacOS, a la iOS. I'll definitely check out the example to see if works on my Catalina machine.

Comment: I'd be willing to jump on a screen share with you as early as this weekend to try to solve this on your machine as well.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Wow. You're amazing. If the example does work for you and the problem is specific to my machine (well, machines, because I have the same issue on my laptop), then I wonder if it is in fact related to my previous use of SoundFlower and an aggregate device that seems to be sticking somehow.

Comment: I have confirmed that the example does in fact work on my Catalina machine. Email me and we can arrange a time to screenshare.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka Sounds great and will do. You have been helpful already by letting me know it’s something about my systems in particular. Thanks!

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I'm getting `AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id ` has this been identified as a hardware issue? My code was running fine before I made some changes. I never touched my declaration of `var metronome = AKMetronome()`

Comment: @MarcusKim I've never encountered an error like that.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka I thought it was weird. I solved the problem by declaring a metronome like this `let metronome = AKMetronome!`, then using init() in order to assign a new object like this `metronome = AKMetronome()`. I don't know why this worked but it did

Comment: 2022 and I still get this error and have no idea how to troubleshoot. Really frustrating.